# Cypress.io how to get length of a array in a before hook, and reuse it later?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

1. My task is to enter the page, get the array length (of the **"a"** tags)
   and store it so I can use in in the next step. I need it once, so I do this firstly in before hook.
2. Forward, I need to get the **"a"** tags and check if they have a **"title"** attribute. This
   case will be looped so many times, as many **"a"** tags are places on the
   web-page. **Thast why I need the array length.**

This is my code, according to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) this isnt a good practice, docs call this "code doing backflips" but it should work:

```
    let sizeVar;

before(() => {
    cy.visit("https://web-page");
    cy.get("a").not("[href='']").not("[href='#']").its("length").then((size) => {
        sizeVar = Cypress.$(size);
        return sizeVar;
    });
})

for (let i = 0; i < sizeVar; i++) {
    it(`tag <a> index ${i}`, () => {
        cy.get("a").not("[href='']").not("[href='#']").eq(i).should("have.attr", "title");
    })
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesnt :( after runing above test in Cypress I have **"No tests found in your file. We could not detect any tests in the above file. Write some tests and re-run."** What the hell?! The funny fact is that when I will change in the loop the sizeVar for some static number, for example 100, it will work and move smoothly.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

But I dont need the static number, I need it done in the right way... According to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) the best way is to use **aliases**. So I did, this is the code:

```
before(() => {
    cy.visit("https://web-page");
    cy.get("a").not("[href='']").not("[href='#']").its("length").as("size");
})

for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
    it(`tag <a> index ${i}`, () => {
        cy.get("a").not("[href='']").not("[href='#']").eq(i).should("have.attr", "title");
    })
}
```

And again I doesnt work, this time I get **"Cannot read property 'size' of undefined"**. Where am I doing mistake? Please help.

=======================UPDATE===============================

I was thinking about to use pure JS but this not work either... I dont see any wrong logic in my code... But Cypress dont want to pass this variable :(

```
describe("test", () => {

let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
let linksLength = links.length;

before(() => {
    cy.visit("https://web-page");
})

for (let i = 0; i < linksLength; i++) {
    it(`tag <a> index ${i}`, () => {
        cy.get("a").not("[href='']").not("[href='#']").eq(i).should("have.attr", "title");
    })
}
})
```

Comment: One way would be to store the size to the cypress env variable then it can be accessed throughout the current test `cy.get("a").not([href='']").not([href='#']").its("length").then((size) => {Cypress.env('arraysize', "size")})`. And then you can use `Cypress.env('arraysize')` for your loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I tryed your solution but got the same result as my "sizeVar" variable: "No tests found in your file. We could not detect any tests in the above file. Write some tests and re-run."

Comment: What is meant by "code doing backflips"?

Comment: dont ask me :) enter here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values ctrl+f "backflip" and see on your own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the for loop is getting evaluated before any testing starts. You can think of it as a two-pass process, the first pass loads the command queue and the second runs the commands.

Best I can find is to split the logging and the testing by using two sequential `.then()` clauses.

**Test**

```
it('finds external links', () => {

  cy.visit("https://web-page");

  cy.get("a").not("[href='']").not("[href='#']") 
    .then($list => {

      // Get the titles 
      const titles = [...$list].map((el) => Cypress.$(el).attr('title') )

      // Log all their values
      titles.forEach((value, index) => {
        cy.log(`tag <a> index ${index} - title is ${value}`)
      })

      // Pass on to next then()
      return cy.wrap(titles)
    })
    .then(titles => {

      // Test the titles
      expect(titles.every(title => title)).to.equal(true, 'All titles are defined')

    })
})
```

**Result**

```
log tag <a> index 0 - title is 1
log tag <a> index 1 - title is undefined
log tag <a> index 2 - title is 3

AssertionError  All titles are defined: expected false to equal true
```

**HTML fragment tested**

```
<div>
  <a href="link1" title="1">1</a>   // ok
  <a href="link2">2</a>             // fails
  <a href="link4" title="3">3</a>   // ok
  <a href="">4</a>                  // ignored
  <a href="#">5</a>                 // ignored
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response, but each() isnt a solution for me. This way I will create one test case which will stop running with very first fail. If I will loop the it() I will asert every element Im interested in. And this works fine when useing for loop with a static number. The issue is to put the size of the loop in a variable.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct that `.each()` fails on the first undefined tag. But I think a for loop is impossible, since you want to screen-scrape the number of tests. There is a way to split the logging and the expectation using chained `.then()`, see amendment.

Comment: So it looks like cypress has some limits that we cant at the moment pass, but your solution is the best way so far. Thank you for the help!

Comment: General best practice is to have a test that does not need screen-scraping (i.e data is known). What scenario requires you to dynamically find the number of elements?